# date: invalid option -- 'c'

Tags: linux, сервер, дата, ssh, hosting

Пытаюсь подключится к хостингу по ssh. Логин и пароль точно правильный. Выводит такую ошибку. В чём дело?

```
$ssh my_login@my_ip
my_login@my_ip`s password:
date: invalid option -- 'c'
Try `date --help` for more information.
Connection to my_ip closed.
```

Comment: похоже на то, что что-то не так в профиле или `bashrc`... попробуй подключиться как `ssh my_login@my_ip /bin/bash --norc --noprofile`... если получится, то смотри, что там не так в `bashrc`/`profile` и пр.

Comment: нет. так тоже самое пишет

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку